# Android how to add image view with two text views in collapsing toolbar layout

Tags: android

I have my collapsing toolbar layout and as a backdrop I have an imageview and on the left side of the collapsing toolbar I want an imageview and right next to this imageview, two textviews below each other. The problem is the framelayout hides half of the image view So I can't find a way to center to the right the image view

Here is my layout file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cover"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/android"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.9" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame_layout_titles"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.3">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_titles"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="bottom|center"
                        android:text="Game title"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:text="Developer name"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Comment: increase the height of frame_layout_titles and then try/ increase the height of collapsing_toolbar if needed

Answer (score 0):

**As i can understand following will help you.**

1. the first thing is that you should not fixed the height of
   collapsing toolbar layout you can use wrap_content .
2. you have to give some size to image View.
3. you can use margin top in second image.
4. you should use margin top in relative layout.

   ```
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/backdrop"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="320dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
       android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
       android:scaleType="centerCrop"
       android:src="@drawable/carrick"
       app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/cover"
       android:layout_width="80dp"
       android:layout_height="80dp"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:scaleType="centerCrop"
       android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
       android:src="@drawable/carrick"
       app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
       app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.9" />

   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/frame_layout_titles"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="74dp"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
       android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
       android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
       app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.3">

       <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/linear_layout_titles"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:orientation="vertical">

           <TextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
               android:gravity="bottom|center"
               android:text="Game title"
               android:textColor="@android:color/white"
               android:textSize="30sp" />

           <TextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
               android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
               android:text="Developer name"
               android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

       </LinearLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>

   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
       app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
       app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
   ```

Comment: if it does not make a clear sense you can share screen shot to your desired output I can help you to provide proper solution